# Is there a way to perform arithmetic operations in mustache templates with spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, mustache

In thymeleaf, I can do something like this.

```html
<td class="pr-4" th:text="${item.price * item.quantity}"></td>
```

FreeMarker also has similar support as shown below.

```html
<td class="pr-4">${item.price * item.quantity}</td>
```

But I am not sure How to bring the same behaviour to Mustache Template. The documentation only concentrates on javascript functions.Is there a way to achieve this in spring boot?

I don't want to calculate the value outside of the template.